# Datatables Only sorts by int with error

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatables set up to read JSON from the server. One of the columns however should be sorted by it's hidden index versus what is displayed on the screen.

This is what I have to display the table:

```
        $("#ad-table").dataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[100, 50, 25], [100, 50, 25]],
            "ajax": {
                "url": "assessmentsduetable?peid="+peId,
                "dataSrc": ""
            },

            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "buttons": ['print', 'pageLength'],
            "order": [[4, "asc"]],
            "columns": [
           { "data": "Consumer ID" },
           { "data": "Last Name" },
        {
            "data": {
                _: "WindowNameInfo.WindowDue",
                sort: "WindowNameInfo.WindowDueIndex"

            }
        },
           { "data": "Window End Date" },
           { "data": "Days Left In Window" },
           { "data": "Assessment Name" },
           { "data": "Date of Last Assessment" },
           { "data": "# of Assessments" },
           { "data": "Clinician" },
           { "data": "Clinic" }
            ]
        });



    });
```

The problem is with WindowNameInfo.WindowDue and WindowNameInfo.WindowDueIndex.  For some reason, it seems to be sorting on WindowDueIndex as if it were a string even though it is an integer. However, when I do this:

```
   "data": {
                    _: "WindowNameInfo.WindowDue",
                    sort: "WindowNameInfo.WindowDueIndex",
                    type: "int"

                }
```

I get the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=ad-table - Requested unknown parameter
>   '[object Object]' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Then it loads the table and the sorting is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the type option tells DataTables where to get the data to use for the type detection.

So the answer is:

...

```
   "data": {

                    _: "WindowNameInfo.WindowDue",
                    sort: "WindowNameInfo.WindowDueIndex",
                    type: "WindowNameInfo.WindowDueIndex",
                }
```

...